# Multi route graphhoper project

Tags: graphhopper

Have a nice day.

I'm creating a project using graphopper and
I want to route all routes for not one, but
several routes from point A to B. How do I do this?
I have tried:

EdgeIteratorState edge = path.calcEdges().get(0);
edge.setDistance(100000);

But the next time you created route, it does not change.
Can you please tell how to make multiple routes?

Comment: You want a one-to-many routing algorithm? Do you want to use the low level API or just working? Did you read https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/routing.md and https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/low-level-api.md ?

Comment: No I want one-to-one - all route.

Comment: You mean if you have N start locations and M end locations you just want all the N*M routes?

Comment: No, I have one start, and one finish, and I want find, and display all route between start and finish.

Comment: What do you mean with 'all' - do you mean alternative routes? 'all' routes would be NP complete and not really possible

Comment: Currently under work, not yet released.